# MySQL query to extract per-player scoreboard data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

- `user_id` (unique per user)
- `user_name`
- `level` (1-4)
- `score`

This table is used to store the scores for a game with 4 levels. A player can play each level as many times as they want. When a level is completed, a new row is added to the database.

I need to write an SQL query that searches the only table for the `user_id` and `user_name` of a player, along with the sum of their highest scores for each of the levels. The results must be sorted in descending order by `sum(score)`.

Comment: Have you written any SQL code so far? If so, please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do this:

```
select
  user_id, 
  user_name, 
  sum(score) as total_score
from (
    select 
      user_id, 
      user_name, 
      level, 
      max(score) as score 
    from t
    group by user_id, user_name, level
) max_level_scores
group by user_id, user_name
order by total_score desc
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3232/1)

Comment: I'm testing now the results manually to be sure. As i see it seems to work as i need!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, sum(maxscore) as overallscore
FROM
    -- subquery to get only the maximum scores
    (SELECT user_id,user_name,level,max(score) as maxscore 
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY  user_id,user_name,level) as maximums -- don't know if MYSQL requires alias
GROUP BY user_id,user_name 
ORDER BY sum(maxscore) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your table implemented using SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table scoreboard(user_name string, level integer, score integer);
sqlite> insert into scoreboard values("bob", 1, 100);
sqlite> insert into scoreboard values("bob", 1, 50);
sqlite> insert into scoreboard values("bob", 2, 200);
sqlite> insert into scoreboard values("bob", 3, 20);
sqlite> insert into scoreboard values("ted", 4, 200);
```

To get the highest score for each player/level, you'd need to do the following:

```
SELECT user_name, level, MAX(score) FROM scoreboard GROUP BY user_name, level;
```

The result:

```
bob|1|100
bob|2|200
bob|3|20
ted|4|200
```

You could then group these results based on player name:

```
SELECT user_name, SUM(hiscore) AS totalscore FROM
(
    SELECT user_name, MAX(score) AS hiscore
    FROM scoreboard
    GROUP BY user_name, level
) GROUP BY user_name ORDER BY totalscore DESC;
```

The result:

```
bob|320
ted|200
```

I'm not sure why you'd have separate `user_name` and `user_id` columns, since only one of these is needed to uniquely identify a player. Assuming you aren't restricted to only one table, the code above could be modified to replace the `user_name` field with a `user_id` column instead, which would be a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for a separate "player names" table:

#### playernames

```
1|bob
2|ted
3|steve
4|james
```

#### scoreboard

```
1|1|100
1|1|50
1|2|200
1|3|20
2|4|200
```